# Expected Statement

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

Hello i'm working on a test Website where I want a User to be able to look at entries in a Database, the User can Choose if he wants the Data from Customers, the Adress, or the Order. 
When i open it, ist says expected statement on `wend` at line 82.

Here is my Code:

```
     <form action="DB_HTML_Styled.asp" method="get">
  <%
  response.flush
%>
<table border = "1" width = "500" heigth = "500" align = "Center">
  <tr>
        <td align = "left" width =  "100">
          <select name = "f_operator" onchange"">
            <option value = "1" <% if l_operator = "1" then response.write("selected") end if %>>Kunde</option>
            <option value = "2" <% if l_operator = "2" then response.write("selected") end if %>>Auftrag</option>
            <option value = "3" <% if l_operator = "3" then response.write("selected") end if %>>Ort</option>
        </td>
  </tr> 
<%  Set l_DBCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    l_DBCon.Open "db_amill136_test"
    Dim l_rs
    Set l_rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
select case l_operator
case "1"
    l_query = "select * from t_kunde"
case "2"
    l_query = "select * from t_auftrag"
case "3"
    l_query = "select * from t_ort"
case "4"

%>
  <tr><td><%=l_query%></td></td>
  <%
    l_rs.Open l_query, l_dbcon
    while not l_rs.EOF  %>

<%if l_operator =  "1" then %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_vorname")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_name")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_kundennr")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_ortnr")%>
    </td>
    <%else if l_operator =  "2" then%>
        <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_auftragsnr")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_menge")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_rabatsatz")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_datum")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_kundennr")%>
    </td>
    <%else if l_operator =  "3" then%>
      <%=l_rs("f_ortnr")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_ort")%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=l_rs("f_plz")%>
    </td>
  </tr>
<%end if
        l_rs.MoveNext
      wend

    l_rs.Close
    Set l_rs = Nothing

    l_DBCon.Close
    set l_DBCon = Nothing
%>

  </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, you would need three "end if" statements before the wend because you have three separate "if" statements within the "while".

Instead of using "Else If" (with a space) use "ElseIf" (without a space) so you only need the one "end if".

Alternatively, you may wish to tidy up those nested ifs by using a Case instead.

Comment: Thank solved my Problem. I deleted the spaces, and added a end select ins line 87.